# CheckBoxPreference group that act like Radio

Tags: android-preferences

I wanted to have multiple CheckBoxPreferences on the same screen that would act like a radio list.
I saw some implementations of it, but eventually I wrote something of my own.
Perhaps it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

1) Build a group class, such as:

```
public class CheckBoxPreferenceGroup {

    private List<CheckBoxPreference> mGroup; 

    public CheckBoxPreferenceGroup(PreferenceManager manager, String[] keys) {

        mGroup = new ArrayList<CheckBoxPreference>(keys.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            final CheckBoxPreference cbx = (CheckBoxPreference) manager.findPreference(keys[i]);

            cbx.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                    onCheckBoxClick(cbx);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            mGroup.add(cbx);
        }
    }

    private void onCheckBoxClick(CheckBoxPreference newChecked) {

        CheckBoxPreference oldChecked = null;

        for (CheckBoxPreference item : mGroup) {
            if (item != newChecked && item.isChecked()) {
                oldChecked = item;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (oldChecked != null)
            oldChecked.setChecked(false);
    }
}
```

2) Provide it with a array of Strings (String[] keys) so that it will search the Preferences.

3) Use it like so:

```
public static class ScreenSettingsPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    private static CheckBoxPreferenceGroup mAlertGroup;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences_screen_notifications);
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.xml.preferences, false);

        PreferenceManager pm = getPreferenceManager();

        mAlertGroup = new CheckBoxPreferenceGroup(pm, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pref_checkboxes));
    }
}
```

Where **pref_checkboxes** is my string array of checkboxes keys:

```
<string-array name="pref_checkboxes">
    <item>pref_cbx1</item>
    <item>pref_cbx2</item>
    <item>pref_cbx3</item>
    <item>pref_cbx4</item>
</string-array>
```